# Как добавить полоски на задний фон?

Tags: html, css

Как добавить зеленые полоски на задний фон?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfKg7.jpg

Comment: Полоски добавить можно с помощью написания соответствующего кода, предварительно изучив основы HTML и CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать таким способом это сделать:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 100px 1fr;
  width: 670px;
  height: 250px;
}

.wrapper>.green-line {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: end;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.card>button {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="green-line"></div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Даже незнал что можно так решить мою проблему) Спасибо.